# Restarting the MSDTC service from a wpf app

Tags: wpf, msdtc

MSDTC service keeps shutting it self down when using multiple entity framework data models. The only solution is to manually restart the MSDTC service, how can I restart the service using c# in a wpf application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDTC runs as a regular Windows service under the name "Distributed Transaction Coordinator". You can stop and start it using the ServiceController class (using System.ServiceProcess).